# How can I work with the data constructors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with working with data constructors and would be happy if someone could help. So I have a data type `Colors` which constructors are numbers from 0 to 3. And now I want to evaluate which color is more severe (has a higher number). I tried this code

```
data Color = Green | Yellow | Orange | Red

severity :: Color -> Integer
severity Green = 0
severity Yellow = 1
severity Orange = 2
severity Red = 3

moreSevere :: Color -> Integer -> Bool
moreSevere xs ys = if xs > ys then True
  else False
```

but it doesn't work and gives me an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Color’ with actual type ‘Integer’
    • In the second argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘ys’
      In the expression: xs > ys
      In the expression: if xs > ys then True else False
   |
66 | moreSevere xs ys = if xs > ys then True
```

does any of you know how to solve this?

Comment: The error message seems very clear to me - could you explain what you do and don't understand about it?

Comment: If you add `deriving Enum` to your definition, then `severity = fromEnum`.

Comment: May I just congratulate you for a very clear question from a new user. This is fun to read.

Answer (score 9):

> So I have a data type "Colors" which constructors are numbers from 0 to 3

no you don't. You have a data type whose constructors are `Green`, `Yellow`, `Orange` and `Red` – which makes sense as those are colours, whereas in my book 2 is not a colour.

What is indeed “numbers from 0 to 3” are the *severities* of those colours. In your function, you're apparently trying to compare a given threshold to the severity of a colour. So you need to write that too –

```
       ... if severity xs > ys then ...
```

I don't like your choice of parameter names here – we usually use `xs` for some list (the elements of which would be `x` then), but you don't have any lists. Why not

```
moreSevere c threshold = ...
```

Also, your `if` statement is superfluous: `if cond then True else False` is exactly the same as simply `cond` alone. So,

```
moreSevere c threshold = severity c > threshold
```

You can shorten this further, using [eta-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction), to

```
moreSevere c = (severity c >)
```

or even

```
moreSevere = (>) . severity
```

but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

You are simply reimplementing the existing `Enum` and `Ord` type classes. The compiler can derive them for you.

```
data Color = Green | Yellow | Orange | Red deriving (Enum, Eq, Ord)

severity :: Color -> Integer
severity = fromEnum

moreSevere :: Color -> Color -> Bool
moreSevere = (>)

moreSevere' :: Color -> Integer -> Bool
moreSevere' c n = severity c > n
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the answers! I have to admit that i didn't quite understand your suggestions because this is my first semester of computer science and the things you suggested will I probably learn just later on. But I wanted to update you that I found another solution for it:

```
moreSevere :: Color -> Color -> Bool
moreSevere x y = if severity x > severity y then True
  else False
```

I think I just had to change the "Integer" for "Color". But thank you all for your help!

Comment: `if <A> then true else false` can just be written as `<A>`, because if `<A>` is `true`, the `if` as a whole will return `true` as well, and if `<A>` is `false` the `if` will just return the same `false` value. so this `if` doesn't change anything.  :)